# What methods exist, if any, for adding a power from one class list to another class list?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, powers, psionics

Having looked into the matter, so far the only possibility I'm finding would be to research the power in question the same way one would create a new power or spell...

Are there any other methods?

Please exclude Manipulate Form or similar degrees of TO.

Comment: Do you wish to exclude Manipulate Form and similar levels of TO?

Comment: Ah, yes, yes I would.

Answer (score 2):

The [Mind’s Eye article “Expanded Classes, Part Four”](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/psm/20070629a) includes guidance for **Substitute Powers** in a psionic mantle. Since an ardent’s power list is the list of powers found on their chosen mantles, substituting the powers on a mantle changes the power list for that character.

I don’t believe there is any other method. The existence of the Expanded Knowledge feat eliminates much need for this kind of effect, and psionics simply doesn’t have the colossal quantity of material that magic does, so it’s less likely for something ill-advised to have slipped through.

Comment: Yeah, good point. Psionic powers number between 6 and 7 hundred total, depending on how one counts duplicates and updates.